# convert date and hour to datetime python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using Pyhon 3.8, pandas 1.1.2

MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2020-07-20", "2020-07-20", "2020-07-20", "2020-07-20"],
                   "hour":["1", "2", "3", "4"]})

df["datetime"]  = df["date"] + " " + df["hour"]
```

This creates dataframe that looks like this:

```
    date       hour     datetime
0   2020-07-20  1   2020-07-20 1
1   2020-07-20  2   2020-07-20 2
2   2020-07-20  3   2020-07-20 3
3   2020-07-20  4   2020-07-20 4
```

I want to make datetime column an actual datetime object.

Desired output would be

```
    date       hour     datetime
0   2020-07-20  1   2020-07-20 01:00:00
1   2020-07-20  2   2020-07-20 02:00:00
2   2020-07-20  3   2020-07-20 03:00:00
3   2020-07-20  4   2020-07-20 04:00:00
```

I want to use this data for plotting a time series graph. datetime format doesn't need to be in specific format as long as it knows increasing order when plotting using plotly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.to_datetime` after `zfill`:

```
df["datetime"]  = df["date"] + " " + df["hour"].str.zfill(2)
pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
```

Output:

```
0   2020-07-20 01:00:00
1   2020-07-20 02:00:00
2   2020-07-20 03:00:00
3   2020-07-20 04:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Perfect. So as long as I have hour with prepending 0 for 1 length values pd.to_datetime works? str.zfill seems like a powerful function, Thanks!

Comment: @Ambleu Yes because the hour part needs to be zero filled number from 00 to 23

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
#pad df.hour with 0 on the left

s=df.hour.str.pad(width=2, side='left', fillchar='0')

#concat using df.str.cat

df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.cat(s+":00:00", sep=' '))

    date      hour        datetime
0  2020-07-20    1  2020-07-20 01:00:00
1  2020-07-20    2  2020-07-20 02:00:00
2  2020-07-20    3  2020-07-20 03:00:00
3  2020-07-20    4  2020-07-20 04:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks! What would be the case where we would use this methods instead of zfill? Is it faster?

Comment: @Ambleu, apart from resolving OP questions, this forum is used  by others to learn. That happens through availing of alternative answers to questions. Mine was an alternative answer. Maybe you knew the method and decided not to use it. For others, knowing `.str.cat()` is an alternative `concat` method or `.pad` can be used as `.zfill `maybe useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using datetime module in python.

**strftime** converts datetime to str,
**strptime** converts str to datetime.

```
base_df["datetime"] = base_df["datetime"].apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(row, "%Y-%m-%d %H"))
```